# How do I update/add to a JSON file using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've created a local JSON file and am able to get data from the file using

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('employees.json').success(function(data){
  $scope.employees=angular.fromJson(data.employees);
  console.log($scope.employees);
});  //this is where the data from the json file is taken and stored into $scope.employees. works fine
}
```

I've been trying to write an equivalent http POST call by doing a `$scope.employees.push`, but it is only (understandably) updating the value of the local variable.

How do I update or add values to the original `employees.json` file?

Comment: you can't do this from client side (it is even beyond the powers of angular to do this). you must write a handler on the server side, and then `post` data back to it to store int he originating `employees.json` file.

Comment: Yes, but the JSON file is stored locally, on the same computer. IS a handler still necessary? If so, can the handler be written in JS or using angular?

Comment: You can use node.js for example if you prefer javascript. Angular is a client only framework, it doesn't support server side.(AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do that directly from Angular. There are some other sources that you integrate into your app, which you can then have Angular leverage.

- [Exploring the FileSystem API (HTML5)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) - verify which browsers
  support this.
- Another options is [jQuery.twFile](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html).

You could also just store it as [`localstorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and access it as you would just about any other object. This would be the method that I'd lean towards more (depending on the size). Otherwise I've always had to have the server-side do it.