# angular.fromJson parsing local json file not working

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing

I have a local json file (data.json) that I am attempting to parse using angular.fromJson which I don't have much familiar using. I've been following this post [How do I update/add to a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923745/how-do-i-update-add-to-a-json-file-using-angularjs). My data.json file is in the same folder as my app.js file yet I am receiving a 404 error message 'localhost:3000/data.json 404 (Not Found)', which makes sense because data.json is not at that address it's at localhost:3000/apps/javascripts/data.json. Do I have to use an absolute url? However when I place data.json directly into angular.fromJson it works.

This works:

```
$scope.menu = angular.fromJson('{
      "name": "Mark",
      "id": 1,
      "project": "AMI",
      "project start": "10/1/2007",
      "project end": "9/31/2008"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ann",
      "id": 2,
      "project": "CLN",
      "project start": "10/1/2007",
      "project end": "9/31/2009"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary",
      "id": 3,
      "project": "CAN",
      "project start": "10/1/2008",
      "project end": "9/31/2011"
    }');
  console.log($scope.menu);
        });
```

This doesn't work:

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
  $scope.menu = angular.fromJson(data.menu);
  console.log($scope.menu);
```

data.json script:

```
{   
"menu": [
      {
      "name": "Mark",
      "id": 1,
      "project": "AMI",
      "project start": "10/1/2007",
      "project end": "9/31/2008"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ann",
      "id": 2,
      "project": "CLN",
      "project start": "10/1/2007",
      "project end": "9/31/2009"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary",
      "id": 3,
      "project": "CAN",
      "project start": "10/1/2008",
      "project end": "9/31/2011"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What happens when you give the full path. Does that reject?

Comment: @Gary I get an error menu is not defined... i've added my json script above

Comment: @Gary yep I got it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: :-) thank christian. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line

`$http.get('data.json').success(function(data){`

to

`$http.get('/apps/javascripts/data.json').success(function(data){`.

Comment: Thanks Christian :)